# Delete all nodes in null terminated doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I'm facing a problem while destroying all the nodes in null-terminated doubly linked list (It is a list where 2 pointers head and tail points at the nodes and the first node's prev and last node's next is null).The null-terminated doubly list looks like this
 [image: Null terminated doubly linked list]).

The code works fine for small input ,but for very large input it gives 
corrupted size vs prefix size error

```
>>Input1 : 12312312312123123123123123123123
>>Input2 : 1
>>Addition : 12312312312123123123123123123124
>>Inside Destroy
*** Error in `./savan': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x0000000002066c40 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f88ba43a7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x83781)[0x7f88ba446781]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x179)[0x7f88ba447839]
./savan[0x401073]
./savan[0x401369]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f88ba3e3830]
./savan[0x400749]
```

This is my code for destroying all the nodes, and the structure defination.

**Structure Defination**

```
typedef struct node{
        char ch;
        struct node *next,*prev;
}node;

typedef struct Integer{
        node *p, *q;
}Integer;
```

**Code for destroyInteger**

```
 void destroyInteger(Integer *a){
    node *tmp = NULL;
    printf("Inside Destroy");
        if(a->p == NULL) //if the Integer is empty then do nothing
            return;
        while(a->p->next != NULL){ //while integer's next not null loop
            tmp = a->p;        //assign to temp and free it
            a->p = a->p->next; // move the pointer ahead
            free(tmp);
        }
        tmp = a->p; //for last node or if only one node as it is double null terminated list
        free(tmp);  
        a->p = NULL; //make the integer null as in initInteger
        a->q = NULL;
    }
```

**Integer.c ADT whole code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include "integer.h"
void initInteger(Integer *a){
    a->p = NULL;
    a->q = NULL;
}

void addDigit(Integer *a, char c){
    node *temp;
    if(isdigit(c)){
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->ch = c;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(a->p == NULL){
            temp->prev = NULL;
            a->p = temp;
            a->q = temp;
        }
        else{
            a->q->next = temp;
            temp->prev = a->q;  
            a->q = temp;
        }
    }
    else
        return;
}
void printInteger(Integer a){
    char c;
    if(a.p == NULL){
        printf("0\n");
        return;
    }
    while(a.p->next != NULL){
        c = a.p->ch;
        putchar(c);
        a.p = a.p->next;
    }
    c = a.p->ch;
    putchar(c);
    putchar('\n');
}
Integer createIntegerFromString(char *str){
    int i = 0, flag = 0;
    char ch;
    Integer res;
    initInteger(&res);
    while(*(str + i) != '\0'){
        if(isdigit(*(str + i))){
            ch = *(str + i);
            addDigit(&res, ch);
            flag = 1;
            i++;
        }
        else
            break;          
    }   
    if(flag == 0){
        addDigit(&res, '0');
    }
    return res;
}
Integer addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b){
    Integer c;
    char num1, num2, *revString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    int n1, n2, carry = 0, counter = 0, sum = 0, flag1 = 0, flag2 = 0, mainflag = 0, i;
    initInteger(&c);
    if(a.p == NULL && b.p == NULL){
        addDigit(&c, '0');
        return c;
    }
    else if(a.p == NULL && b.p != NULL)
        return b;       
    else if(a.p != NULL && b.p == NULL)
        return a;

    else{
        do{     n1 = n2 = 0;
            num1 = num2 = '\0';
            if(a.q->prev == NULL && b.q->prev == NULL)
                mainflag = 1;
            //for a
            if(a.q->prev == NULL && flag1 == 0){
                num1 = a.q->ch;
                n1 = num1 - '0';
                flag1 = 1;
            }
            else if(a.q->prev != NULL){
                num1 = a.q->ch;
                n1 = num1 - '0';
                a.q = a.q->prev;
            }
            else
                n1 = 0;
            //for b
            if(b.q->prev == NULL && flag2 == 0){
                num2 = b.q->ch;
                n2 = num2 - '0';
                flag2 = 1;      
            }
            else if(b.q->prev != NULL){
                num2 = b.q->ch;
                n2 = num2 - '0';
                b.q = b.q->prev;
            }
            else
                n2 = 0; 
            sum = n1 + n2 + carry;
            if(sum >=  10){
                revString[counter++] = (sum % 10) + '0';
                carry = 1;
                sum = 0;
            }
            else{
                revString[counter++] = sum + '0';
                carry = 0;
            }
        revString = (char*)realloc(revString, counter + 1);
        }while(mainflag != 1);
        if(carry == 1){
            revString[counter++] = '1';
        }
        for(i = counter; i > 0; i--){
            addDigit(&c, revString[i-1]);
        }
    }
    free(revString);
    return c;
}
Integer substractIntegers(Integer a, Integer b){
    Integer c;
    char num1, num2, *revString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    int n1, n2, carry = 0, counter = 0, sum = 0, flag1 = 0, flag2 = 0, mainflag = 0, i, len1, len2;
    len1 = length(a);
    len2 = length(b);
    initInteger(&c);
    if(len1 < len2){
        addDigit(&c, '0');
        return c;
    }
    if(a.p == NULL && b.p == NULL){
        addDigit(&c, '0');
        return c;
    }
    else if(a.p == NULL && b.p != NULL)
        return b;       
    else if(a.p != NULL && b.p == NULL)
        return a;

    else{
        do{     n1 = n2 = 0;
            num1 = num2 = '\0';
            if(a.q->prev == NULL && b.q->prev == NULL)
                mainflag = 1;
            //for a
            if(a.q->prev == NULL && flag1 == 0){
                num1 = a.q->ch;
                n1 = num1 - '0';
                flag1 = 1;
            }
            else if(a.q->prev != NULL){
                num1 = a.q->ch;
                n1 = num1 - '0';
                a.q = a.q->prev;
            }
            else
                n1 = 0;
            //for b
            if(b.q->prev == NULL && flag2 == 0){
                num2 = b.q->ch;
                n2 = num2 - '0';
                flag2 = 1;      
            }
            else if(b.q->prev != NULL){
                num2 = b.q->ch;
                n2 = num2 - '0';
                b.q = b.q->prev;
            }
            else
                n2 = 0; 
            sum = n1 - n2 - carry;
            if(sum <  0){
                sum += 10;
                revString[counter++] = sum  + '0';
                carry = 1;
                sum = 0;
            }
            else{
                revString[counter++] = sum + '0';
                carry = 0;
            }
        revString = (char*)realloc(revString, counter);
        }while(mainflag != 1);

        if(carry == 1){
            revString[counter++] = '1';
        }
        for(i = counter; i > 0; i--){
            addDigit(&c, revString[i-1]);
        }
    }
    free(revString);
    return c;
}
int length(Integer l) {
    int len = 0;
    node *tmp;
    tmp = l.p;
    if(!tmp)
        return 0;
    while(tmp->next != NULL){
        tmp = tmp->next;
        len++;
    }
    return len+1;
}
void destroyInteger(Integer *a){
    node *tmp = NULL;
    if(a->p == NULL)
        return;
    while(a->p->next != NULL){
        tmp = a->p;
        a->p = a->p->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
    tmp = a->p;
    a->p = NULL;
    a->q = NULL;
    free(tmp);
}
```

**Main.c for calling and also i have integer.h which is in other file**

```
Integer a, b, c;
    char ch;
    char str[64]; /* This size may change */

    initInteger(&a);
    initInteger(&b);

    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
        addDigit(&a, ch);
    scanf("%s", str);
    b = createIntegerFromString(str);
    c = addIntegers(a, b); 
    printInteger(c);
    destroyInteger(&c);
```

**Integer.h file**

```
typedef struct node{
    char ch;
    struct node *next,*prev;
}node;

typedef struct Integer{
    node *p, *q;
}Integer;

/*Functions*/
void initInteger(Integer *a);
void addDigit(Integer *a, char c);
void printInteger(Integer a);
Integer createIntegerFromString(char *str);
Integer addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b);
Integer substractIntegers(Integer a, Integer b);
void destroyInteger(Integer *a);
int length(Integer a);
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: You probably have memory corruption elsewhere.

Comment: My code works fine without destroyInteger @BLUEPIXY .

Comment: Where are you detecting the corruption? Your code doesn't match the output you show. Can you provide the rest of the code?

Comment: _My code works fine_ : I think it is doubtful.

Comment: @AustinHastings the corruption is in destroyInteger,i have updated the code ,removed the printf

Comment: `revString = (char*)realloc(revString, counter);` should be `revString = (char*)realloc(revString, counter+1);`

Comment: How are you decclaring an `Integer` in your `main`? `Integer *a = malloc (sizeof *a);`? or are you trying to use a static node `Integer a;`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes sorry i even did that and that's actually right ,but still i get the error

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin static node

Comment: I think we may be on to something. What happens when it is shuffled to the middle of list an hit with a `free` by `destroyInteger`? Better declare it dynamically so you don't loose track of which node cannot be passed to `free`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin no we are starting from the start of the list as we are starting it from the header node and traversing all the way to the end

Comment: So,

What is the current problem?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY same for very large inputs the corruption error occurs

Comment: Ok, I see you skip freeing the first node.

Comment: maybe `char str[64];`... `scanf("%s", str);` Also check return value of `realloc` (and `malloc`).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no even i tried making it 1000

Comment: The problem is with destroyInteger, without it im not getting that error @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Don't be so sure about that. I'm still digesting your code. I suspect it is more subtle than just being in `destroyInteger`.

Comment: Your problem is NOT with `destroyInteger`. I can  `createIntegerFromString`, `printInteger` `length` and `destroyInteger` on any number of integers WITHOUT any memory error or leak. It may very well be with how you are using `Integer` within your code, but it is not with these functions themselves.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin okay ill check for it. Thanks. Could you be more specfic with **how you are using Integer**.Thanks once again.

Comment: A lot of it will be with subtle issues as @AustinHastings picked up in his answer. Since you are using static declarations for your terminating nodes, you must vigilant that you never combine `Integers` (leaving a static node *within* a larger number) or otherwise create a condition where you accidentally call `free` on a static end, etc..

Comment: Like @DavidC.Rankin, I tried running your code with some test cases and was unable to produce any kind of corruption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I did notice is this code in `addIntegers`:

```
else if(a.p == NULL && b.p != NULL)
    return b;
```

If you set

```
c = addIntegers(a, b)
```

This code will make `c` a copy of `b`, but both `c` and `b` will point to the same nodes. If you then destroy `c` (or `b`), the other one will have pointers to released memory, which is a recipe for failure.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest that once you have this fixed, you submit it to [`codereview`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for further cleanup.

Comment: Yes you are right ,about that i din't noticed it.Anyways the part is only executed if my first input i.e a is null.My problem is im providing both the input's the calculations are correct but when i free the Integer c with destroyInteger im getting that error of corrupt memory

Comment: It's also true the other way, since there's a clause for the reverse case. But still it doesn't seem to affect the example you showed.